# delegate in UI Thread update from worker (XAML)

Tags: multithreading, xaml, user-interface, worker-thread

i want to update some GUI Elements within the GUI Thread from a WorkerThread. 
The GUI (Class MainPage) specifies a delegate function like the following way.

```
HRESULT MainPage::delegateUpdateGUI(IXRDependencyObject* pSender, XREventArgs* pArgs) {
Mutex.lock();
...
Mutex.lock();
Sleep(20);
this-> m_textbox->SetText(counter_string);
```

}

A Delegate ptr is declared outside

```
IXRDelegate<XREventArgs, IXRDependencyObject> *m_delegateFunction;
```

and is loaded within the MainPage::OnLoaded Method:

```
m_delegateFunction = CreateDelegate(this, &MainPage::delegateUpdateGUI);
```

In my WorkerThread:

```
...
DWORD WINAPI WorkerProc(LPVOID pParam) {
   Mutext.Lock();
   Counter++;
   ...
   Mutex.unlock(),
   m_delegateFunction->Invoke(myMainPage, NULL);
   Sleep(20);
}
```

When i run it with this Sleep(X) condition greater than 10ms it is working, but without that sleep calls an Exeception is thrown ....

Does anybody know why the exception is thrown and what is wrong or missing?